# EF Code First Migration - Naming the column for complex type properties

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, ef-code-first-mapping

I'm converting an existing EF model to use code first.

It has a number of Complex Types, that have a specific db field naming convention:

```
<propertyName>_<complexTypeName>_<complexTypeProperty>
```

So for example, this Complex Type:

```
public class ContactDetails {
    public string Address1 {get;set;}
    public string City {get;set;}
    // ...etc
}
```

Is used in this Entity:

```
public class Customer {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ContactDetails BillingAddress {get;set;}
    public ContactDetails DeliveryAddress {get;set;}
}
```

It appears in a database table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customers (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(30),
    BillingAddress_ContactDetails_Address1 NVARCHAR(100),
    BillingAddress_ContactDetails_City NVARCHAR(100),
    DeliveryAddress_ContactDetails_Address1 NVARCHAR(100),
    DeliveryAddress_ContactDetails_City NVARCHAR(100)
)
```

So I need to change the default naming convention for complex types. I can manually update every column name using Fluent like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(x => x.BillingAddress.Address1).HasColumnName("BillingAddress_ContactDetails_Address1");
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(x => x.BillingAddress.City).HasColumnName("BillingAddress_ContactDetails_City");
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(x => x.DeliveryAddress.Address1).HasColumnName("DeliveryAddress_ContactDetails_Address1");
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(x => x.DeliveryAddress.City).HasColumnName("DeliveryAddress_ContactDetails_City");
```

The problem is that `ContactDetails` is used many many times throughout the database in many different tables. So I want configure them all in one go. I need something like this:

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<ContactDetails>().Property(x => x.Address1).HasColumnName($"{???}_{???}_Address1");
modelBuilder.ComplexType<ContactDetails>().Property(x => x.City).HasColumnName($"{???}_{???}_City");
```

But how do I fill in the `{???}` parts? Where can I get property name and type name from in this context?

Comment: Is there a reason you are [de-normalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the database?

Comment: @Steve Greene: Yes, but it has no bearing on this question.